# How does Heroku Django picks up settings file during production? Multiple settings

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, heroku, deployment

It's my first time deploying so I just want to make sure that I understand.

Basically, how does heroku django determine which setting file to choose when its deployed?
Are there any command that I can type in order to check which setting file its currently using?  like if its a prod or dev.

^^ To answer the above question on my own, you set myproject.settings.prod in wsgi file and heroku config:set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings.prod to tell it to choose your prod settings for production/deploymnent. Am I correct in my understanding? Thanks in advance. Any advice or feedback would be apprecated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the answer you came up with is logically correct but might not work.

Change your `wsgi.py` to set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE; looking at where it is being run on: (You will have to set environment variable ENV=Heroku in heroku for this)

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

if os.getenv("ENV") == "Heroku":
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_app.production_settings')
else:
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_app.dev_settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

You can also change your `manage.py` to have the same incase you want to use `manage.py runserver` for development ease:

```
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""

    if os.getenv("ENV") == "Heroku":
        os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_app.production_settings')
    else:
        os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_app.dev_settings')

    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Q: Why this approach instead of your solution to directly set the env variable in heroku?

A: I haven't tested it, but on each restart `wsgi.py` runs `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_app.settings')` overwriting the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable manually set by you in heroku. So, you will have to set it in wsgi.py.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That really help especially the wsgi overwritting part! thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to thank you for your answer but I've managed it in a little bit different way. Because I've split settings files and the purpose was to load an appropriate config file based on environment variable I've resolve it by:

```
if os.environ.get("DJANGO_ENV") == 'prod':
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'config.settings.prod'
elif os.environ.get("DJANGO_ENV") == 'dev':
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'config.settings.dev'
elif os.environ.get("DJANGO_ENV") == 'test':
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'config.settings.test'
```

Why? Because  os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_app.production_settings') always returned my_app.settings.
So the question is how it works? Pretty simple, firstly "setdefault" checks environment variables for **DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE**, if it didn't found then it is set as is in code (my_app.production.settings) but probably in most cases it will exist there so instead of using setdeault we should assign a new value for this variable like **os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'config.settings.prod'**